# what is Target: x86_64-redhat-linux?

Tags: c++, g++

I gave "g++ -v" on command prompt to check the 
compiler version.
Output is:

```
Using built-in specs.
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: 
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)
```

What is mean by target, thread model here?

Answer (score 4):

It tells you what the build parameters where when the g++ comiler was built:

1. x86_64 being the processor architecture (other examples of choices would be i386, arm, 68k, itanium).
2. redhat the variant of the OS target. This is really just an identifier of what flavour the build is.
3. linux the actual OS target. Other options would be solaris, hp-ux, windows or aix, for example.

It also tells you that the "thread model" is posix (as opposed to for example a windows threading model).

And finally, the version of the source code, the date (4th of July 2008 in YYYYMMDD format) and the Red Hat build version (52nd build of version 4.1.2).

Note that this is pretty much something that won't change for your particular system - the only way to change it is to build a new compiler from source.